# How to find not used django settings

Tags: python, django, settings

In large project, settings file can be really huge. Sometimes after a few months of heavy development, it turns out that there are some variables in settings file, which are not used at all. This might happen after upgrading requirements, or just because someone forgot to remove setting after refactorization the code.

It is very difficult, to check which variables are not needed, because this action requires not only searching through all project files, but also through sources of packages.

Of course, even this not guarantee success, because always somewhere can be something like this: `getattr(settings, '%s_%s' % (app_name, important_setting))`... but this is another story.

1. Is there any IDE/analyzing tool capable of detecting that?
2. Is there a better way for checking this manually?
3. What are the best practices, which helps avoiding this kind of situation

The good news is, that in project on which I am working on we tests almost everything, so after a deleting a specific setting, I can run tests, and check if this broke something... but I don't think, that relying only on this tests a reasonable.

Answer (score -1):

[PyLint](http://docs.pylint.org/) will help you with this. Check out docs and you will find what you need.

Comment: Are you sure, that pylint will do the job for django settings? I think it might be a specific case, because _not used settings_ from user perspective, are actually used by django: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/__init__.py#L85